# Auto accept customer group registrations in Shopware 6

Tags: shopware6

We have enabled registrations form per customer group. Registrations will come in but have to be accepted by an admin. We want to accept the registrations automatically.

We tried it using the flow builder, but it seems that there is no trigger yet for the action "customer group registration", there are only triggers for "customer group accepted" and "declined".

Is the event `checkout.customer.sales_channel.register.customer` a good starting point to write a custom plugin? Or is not customization necessary / is there an easier way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without coding, it does not seem possible to do so with out-of-the-box methods.

- In the flow builder there is currently now event for the request-group event, only for it's success
- Also it's not possible to filter by the requested-group

As a workaround I managed to mark the special users using a `campaignCode` and `affiliateCode`. Then, with a flow builder trigger "Registration" it's possible to assign the proper groups.